# Is it possible to assign works to each GPU thread instead of a work to group of GPU threads?

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, opencl

What I mean by the title is, I have implemented a ray tracing program. In the program, I divided my arrays into chunks because of the memory issiues. After each chunk of rays traced, I am sending new chunks to the openCL kernel. But in a chunk, when only one ray still bouncing and all other rays are traced, already finished rays will need to wait for one ray. This is not very efficient. What I want to do is, assign a chunk of rays to each thread in CPU side and when a thread finished with its chunk they will send a signal to the cpu and I will assign that thread another chunk of rays.

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Within a workgroup (here chunk of rays), the finished rays always have to wait for the remaining ones.

What you can do however is to make a chunk compute the rays for a square of 8x8 pixels on the screen, so that there is a high chance that all these rays (with very similar directions) also do a similar amount of intersections. This is faster than making a chunk a stripe of 64x1 pixels, where the probability is larger that bounces will be different between left and right side of the stripe. See [my technical talk on this](https://youtu.be/pD8JWAZ2f8o?t=1071).

Finally, your kernel range should be the entire image at once, with only a single execution. Don't schedule single workgroups one-by-one, let the GPU scheduler do this for you.

Comment: Then my next question is when majority of the rays are finished and some rays still bouncing, majority of my threads stay idle. Can I sent the already traced rays to the CPU and ask for some new rays (chunk) ? This means some rays from the first chunk still being traced while I am continuously transffering rays from GPU to CPU and vice versa?

Comment: No, you have to wait until the entire kernel is finished. Since only finished rays in a workgroup have to wait for the last in the workgroup, the idling is not too bad. When a workgroup is done, the GPU scheduler automatically deploy a new workgroup on the hardware as long as there is unprocessed ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Finally, You said "Finally, your kernel range should be the entire image at once, with only a single execution. Don't schedule single workgroups one-by-one, let the GPU scheduler do this for you." Normally, I send my chunks in a for loop based on the number of chunks and track the index for ne next chunk. Did you mean that I should send all the rays to the GPU once and let the GPU side to handle even tough there is no enough memory? If so, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Yes, send all rays at the GPU at once, can be in the billions and the GPU will handle it no problem. The reason is to achieve hardware saturation, that means all execution units if the GPU are busy for prolonged time. How is VRAM capacity not enough, don't you need the full scene geometry in VRAM also to only render a part of the image?